# Reading system properties with SPeL in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

I need to get the following system property within one of my configuration files: `-Dspring.profiles.active="development"`. Now I have seen countless of people suggest that this can be done with Spring Expression Language, but I cannot get it to work. Here is what I have tried (plus many variations hereof).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { ... })
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfileOne;

    @Value("#{systemProperties['spring.profiles.active']}")
    private String activeProfileTwo;

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        Resource[] resources = {
            new ClassPathResource("application.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("database.properties")

            // I want to use the active profile in the above file names
        };

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

All of the properties are `NULL`. The same happens if I try to access any other system property. I can access them without problems by invoking `System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")`, but this is not as nice.

Many examples that I found configure the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to also search system properties, so maybe this is why it does not work. However, those examples are in Spring 3 and XML configuration, setting a property that no longer exists on the class. Perhaps I have to call the `setPropertySources` method, but I am not entirely sure how to configure this.

Either way, I found multiple examples that suggest that my approach should work. Believe me, I searched around a lot. What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you wiring properties in the same configuration class where you're registered `PropertiesPalceHolderConfigurer`?

Comment: BTW, you can use `@PropertySources` annotation over the config class, to avoid having to write all those codes in the `@Bean` method. You just have to return `new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` in that case.

Comment: @RohitJain It's because I want to dynamically load properties files based on the environment/Spring profile, such as development.

Comment: In that case, you've to register 2 `PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer`, one for reading System variable, and another for reading the file given by that variable. I would better be using `System.getProperty` here. Or maybe, someone else might come up with a better approach.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I will play around with it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Just autowire an instance of Spring's [`Environment` interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html), as you're actually doing and then ask what the active environment is:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {

        List<String> envs = Arrays.asList(this.environment.getActiveProfiles());
        if (envs.contains("DEV")) {
            // return dev properties
        } else if (envs.contains("PROD")) {
            // return prod properties
        }
        // return default properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the problem is that the `environment` variable is `NULL` when I try to do that.

Comment: OK.  That's because you have to set it at app  startup time

Comment: Set it to the application context

Comment: Does that mean that I should set it within my `web.xml` as a `context-param`? I did this before, but I removed it because then I would have to change the source code in order to change the active profile. I am still pretty new to Spring, so if that's not what you meant, then I apologize.

Comment: I don't know by xml, but by code you can do it with a setter, I believe it's `setEnvironment()` on `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.